# How do I prevent 3 overlapping images in HTML, CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 3 cards that stand at the bottom of the webpage but the 3 cards are overlapping. Can you help me find my mistake please? :)

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 455px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4%;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.397);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front1.png" style="width: 100%;" height="320px">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Create checklists</b></h3>
      <p>Make your own customizable checklist to remain happy and healthy</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front2.jpeg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Take notes</b></h3>
      <p>Write your own notes with fun, colourful tools</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front3.jpeg" style="width: 100%;" height="320px">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Create calendars</b></h3>
      <p>Add pictures to your calendars and customize according to your preferences</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: All three have   position: absolute;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the position: absolute; style in your CSS. Basically, you set all 3 cards to the same position which is why they overlapped.
I also changed your card's height to min-height. This is because the text was flowing out of the card and min-height would prevent this.

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.144);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 13px;
  width: 320px;
  min-height: 455px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.397);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front1.png" style="width: 100%;" height="320px">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Create checklists</b></h3>
      <p>Make your own customizable checklist to remain happy and healthy</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front2.jpeg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Take notes</b></h3>
      <p>Write your own notes with fun, colourful tools</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="resources/images/Front3.jpeg" style="width: 100%;" height="320px">
    <div class="container">
      <h3><b>Create calendars</b></h3>
      <p>Add pictures to your calendars and customize according to your preferences</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "position: absolute" and things would work fine. Or if you're trying to display somethign else?